# python double y axis set aspect ratio

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis

http://onlyamodel.com/2009/dual-units-in-scientific-plots/

how to set double y axis (2 y axis for the same data but with different units). 
Then I wanted to set aspect ration for my plot using

```
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')
```

but it doesn't work. I got this:

```
ValueError: adjustable must be "datalim" for shared axes
```

Can anyone help me with this? 
thx

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,11))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)


xmin = -60
xmax = 60
ymin = 0.0
ymax = 220.0
axis([xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax])

ax.yaxis.tick_left()
ax.grid(True,linestyle='-',color='0.75')
ax.set_axisbelow(True)

cax = ax.scatter(x, z, s=intenzita, c=strain, marker = 'o',         linewidth =   '0.5', cmap = cm.jet, vmin = -0.005, vmax     = -0.000)# strain13 a ine

cbar = plt.colorbar(cax)
cbar.ax.tick_params(labelsize=20) 

ax.set_xlim(-60, 60)
ax.set_ylim(0, 220)



ymin2 = yconv(ymin)
ymax2 = yconv(ymax)
print ymax2
ax2 = twinx()
ylabel('Depth (cm)', fontsize=20)
axis([xmin, xmax, ymin2, ymax2])
ax2.yaxis.tick_right()
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')

ax.tick_params(labelsize = 20)
ax.set_xlabel('x grain position [%sm]'%mi, fontsize=25)

ax.set_ylabel('z grain position [%sm]'%mi, fontsize=30)
cbar.set_label('%s_11'%epsilon, color = 'k', fontsize = 30) #strain

plt.show()
```

x, z, intenzita, strain are all lists

Comment: Could you please provide a minimal example of your plotting script?

Comment: If I copy-paste this, this does not work. After guessing the imports, the data for your scatter plot is still missing.

Comment: I solved it already. I put the plt.gca().set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')
 on the top and it works now. Thanks anyway!